# Java grading program for a class with grading policies

Tags: java, methods

I have to write grading program for a class with the following grading policies.

> 1.there are 2 quizzes, each graded on the basis of 10 points.
>
> 2.there is 1 midterm exam and one final exam, each graded on the basis of 100 points.
>
> 3.the final exam counts for 50% of the grade, the midterm counts for 25%, and the 2 quizzes together count for a total of 25%. (Do not
>   forget to normalize the quiz scores.)

A letter grade will be given based on the following criterion:
90 – 100 A
80 – 89  B
70 – 79  C
60 – 69  D
0 – 59   E

The program will read in the student’s scores from a text file, and output the student’s record, which consists of the name, 2 quiz and 2 exam scores as well as the student’s average numeric score for the entire course and final letter grade.
I am suppose to define and use a class for the student record. All the scores are integers and a student name consists of no more than 10 characters. I must justify your output file.

this was originally given by the instructor I just don't know where to star

```
import java.until.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assign7{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
    Record.setGP(1.25, 1.25, 0.25, 0.50);

 Scanner myIn = new Scanner( new File("scores.txt") );

 public static void main getLetterGrade  
   if (finalScore > 90)  
       letter = 'A'; 
  else if (finalScore > 80) 
     letter = 'B';
  else if (finalScore > 70)  
     letter = 'C';
  else if (finalScore > 60)
     letter = 'D';
  else  
     letter = 'F';

    System.out.println( myIn.nextLine() +"  avg  "+"letter");

    while( myIn.hasNext() ){
       Record myR = new Record(myIn.next(), myIn.nextInt(), myIn.nextInt(), myIn.nextInt(),
myIn.nextInt());

       System.out.println( myR );

    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you send me your instructor's e-mail address I can consult him/her directly and get an answer for you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a homework problem?  If so, please use the "homework" tag to identify it as such.  It helps us know to give you hints instead of answers.

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: I get a whole bunch of them... i just can fix it

Comment: You should go through some basic java tutorials.  You have a large number of syntax errors that will be better taught to you by a tutorial than by someone here in a single answer to this question.

Answer (score 8):

Let's just go this far:

```
// Why not "class" (lower case)?
// Should "class Assign7" be "public" (is it the main class in the module)?
// Did you put any "import" statements above this?
Class Assign7{

   // Do you want to declare any member data before you start your "main()" function?
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

   // Is "Record.setGP()" a "static method"?
   Record.setGP(1.25, 1.25, 0.25, 0.50);

  // Isn't this class-wide data?  If so, shouldn't you put it *above* "main()"?    
  int quiz1, quiz2;
  int tMidterm, tFinal,tQuiz
  int midterm = 0;
  int finalExam = 0;
  String name;
  char grade;


  // Do you really want to just bomb out of the program if this fails?
  Scanner myIn = new Scanner( new File("scores.txt") );

   // Whoa!!!!  Why are we starting a new function, *inside of "main()"*?!?!
   void getScore()  
   {  
   tQuiz = ((quiz1 + quiz2)/20)*.25;  
   tMidTerm = (midTermExam/100)*.25;  
   tFinal = (finalExam/100)*.50;  
   finalScore = tQuiz + tMidTerm + tFinal;  
   }

   // It looks like we're starting a new function here, too.
   // Where's your parenthesis and curly brace after "getLetterGrade"????  
   void getLetterGrade  


   if (finalScore >= 90)  
   {  
   grade = 'A';  
   }  

   // Supposing the grade was "99"?  
   // Would the student get a "B" here?  Or even a "D" below???
   if (finalScore >= 80)  
   {  
   grade = 'B';  
   }
   ...
```

SUGGESTION:

1. Write the smallest, minimal program that just "compiles".
2. Add one thing at a time.  Verify that the change works.
3. Take "baby steps" to a complete solution.
4. Post back specific questions about specific problems as needed.

Comment: 1+. And if you're not using an IDE, then compile ***often*** and fix any found problems immediately. Don't add any new code until the current codes compiles correctly.

Comment: I am trying to fix the program can you just give me a hand

Comment: They are giving you a hand.  You need to start over with what you understand (and what compiles) then build from there.  Add small things to the code and don't move on to the next part until it compiles.  Define simple methods outside of the main.

Comment: @pasito: you are getting excellent suggestions from multiple members. Please don't expect or ask for a spoon-fed answer though. If you run into specific problems when implementing their advice, ask specific questions, and you'll likely get prompt answers.

Comment: paulsm4, that's more help in one program than I got from my comp sci all year. that's a lot of help on homework.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, if only the "specific questions, prompt answers" worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

You have a lot of problems with your code and do not seem to understand Java syntax at all.  Do not try to define methods INSIDE of main.  They should be defined outside of the main.

I don't really know where to start so I'll suggest one thing you need to change badly:

```
if (finalScore >= 90)  
{  
grade = 'A';  
}  
if (finalScore >= 80)  
{  
grade = 'B';  
}
# etc...
```

Say the `finalScore` is `100`.  Then the condition in the first `if` will evaluate to `true` and `grade` will be assigned `'A'`.  Then the next `if` statement: 100 is greater than 80 so this also evaluates to `true`.  Do you see the problem?  `grade` will be reassigned to `'B'`.

Please read the documentation to understand how `else if` and `else` statements will help you here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html
(The example is how to assign grades actually, the exact problem you are working on!)